# Sum nested lists based on condition in Python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list looking like this:

```
[['Vienna','2012', 890,503,70],['London','2014', 5400, 879,78],
 ['London','2014',4800,70,90],['Bern','2013',300,450,678], 
 ['Vienna','2013', 700,850,90], ['Bern','2013',500,700,90]]
```

What I want to do is summing every integervalue in the sublist with another sublist if city and year are equal. I first thought of a dictionary with city and year as key, but it caused problems sorting it.

Then I had: `{('Vienna','2012'):[890,503,70],('Bern','2013'):[800,1150,768],...}`

I also tried something like this:

`[sum(x) for x in zip(*list) if x[0] == x[0]]` but of course it did not work.

Can I do something like this with a nested list to so sorting it by city and year would be easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct a result `dict` where key is tuple of first two items in the original lists and value is `list` of numbers. Every time you add value to `dict` you could use [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to either return existing element or given default value, in this case empty list.

Once you have the existing list and list to add you can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue` to get numbers to sum from both lists. `zip_longest` returns tuples of length 2 containing one number from each list. In case one list is longer than other `fillvalue` is used as default so this will also work in case lists have different lengths. Finally list comprehension could used to sum each item for a new value:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = [
    ['Vienna','2012', 890,503,70],['London','2014', 5400, 879,78],
    ['London','2014',4800,70,90],['Bern','2013',300,450,678],
    ['Vienna','2013', 700,850,90], ['Bern','2013',500,700,90]
]

res = {}
for x in l:
    key = tuple(x[:2])
    res[key] = [i + j for i, j in zip_longest(res.get(key, []), x[2:], fillvalue=0)]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{('Vienna', '2013'): [700, 850, 90], ('London', '2014'): [10200, 949, 168], 
 ('Vienna', '2012'): [890, 503, 70], ('Bern', '2013'): [800, 1150, 768]}
```

If you want to sort the cities alphabetically and years latest first you could pass custom `key` to `sorted`:

```
for item in sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0][0], -int(x[0][1]))):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
(('Bern', '2013'), [800, 1150, 768])
(('London', '2014'), [10200, 949, 168])
(('Vienna', '2013'), [700, 850, 90])
(('Vienna', '2012'), [890, 503, 70])
```

Comment: This looks very good.  Use `res = collections.OrderedDict()` to improve.

Comment: Also with  `defaultdict(list)`  you can just write `res[key]` instead of `res.get(key, [])`

Comment: @Gribouillis: This depends entirely on the ordering of expected output. If items are needed in the same order as in original list then it would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the result you want by simply using a dictionary store all the country names and years as one value. Each key in the dictionary is a tuple of the country name and the corresponding year.

Ex: `key = (country,year)`.

This allows us to have the unique values that we need to group them by.

```
L = [
        ['Vienna','2012', 890,503,70],['London','2014', 5400, 879,78],
        ['London','2014',4800,70,90],['Bern','2013',300,450,678],
        ['Vienna','2013', 700,850,90], ['Bern','2013',500,700,90]
    ]

    countries = {}

    for list in L:
        key = tuple(list[0:2])
        values = list[2:]
        if key in countries:
            countries[key] = [sum(v) for v in zip(countries[key],values)]
        else:
            countries[key] = values

    print(countries)
```

out:

```
 {
     ('Vienna', '2012'): [890, 503, 70],
     ('London', '2014'): [10200, 949, 168],
     ('Bern', '2013'): [800, 1150, 768],
     ('Vienna', '2013'): [700, 850, 90]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain a dictionary as you have outlined in the question. Something like this will help,

```
cities = {}
for a in list:
    city_key = a[:1]
    if city_key in cities:
        cities[city_key] = [a + b for a, b in zip(a[2:], cities[city_key])]
    else:
        cities[city_tuple] = a[2:]
```

Comment: Ok i already did it nearly the way you did. the Problem is that I need to sort the output. It should look like this:

Vienna 
2014 ....

2013 ....

what would the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can easily sort the keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split the list of lists into a dict by the key you want (the city and year). Also the `defaultdict` helps squashing all distances into a flat list

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in lst:
...    dct[(item[0], item[1])].extend(item[2:])
```

Now `dct` has the integers grouped by the city and year:

```
>>> dct
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('Vienna', '2013'): [700, 850, 90], ('London', '2014'): [5400, 879, 78, 4800, 70, 90], ('Vienna', '2012'): [890, 503, 70], ('Bern', '2013'): [300, 450, 678, 500, 700, 90]})
```

And you can just sum them:

```
>>> for key in dct:
...    print(key, sum(dct[key]))
... 
(('Vienna', '2013'), 1640)
(('London', '2014'), 11317)
(('Vienna', '2012'), 1463)
(('Bern', '2013'), 2718)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nl = [['Vienna','2012', 890,503,70],['London','2014', 5400, 879,78],
      ['London','2014',4800,70,90],['Bern','2013',300,450,678],
      ['Vienna','2013', 700,850,90], ['Bern','2013',500,700,90]]
d = {}
for l in nl:
    key = l[0] , l[1]
    value = l[2:]
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = value
    else:
        d[key] = [sum(i)for i in zip(d[key], value)]
print(d)
```

out:

```
{('Vienna', '2012'): [890, 503, 70], ('London', '2014'): [10200, 949, 168], ('Bern', '2013'): [800, 1150, 768], ('Vienna', '2013'): [700, 850, 90]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter` functions:

```
import itertools, operator

l = [['Vienna','2012', 890,503,70],['London','2014', 5400, 879,78],
 ['London','2014',4800,70,90],['Bern','2013',300,450,678],
 ['Vienna','2013', 700,850,90], ['Bern','2013',500,700,90]]

getter = operator.itemgetter(0, 1)  # the sequence to be grouped(first two items)
summed = [[k[0],k[1],sum(sum(d[2:]) for d in list(group))]
          for k, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=getter), getter)]

print(summed)
```

The output:

```
[['Bern', '2013', 2718], ['London', '2014', 11317], ['Vienna', '2012', 1463], ['Vienna', '2013', 1640]]
```